# Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : attempt to select less than one element in get1index >

Tags: r, r-sp

I want to use the `thin` command in the spThin package. It worked properly yesterday and it will not work tonight!!! Same code! I cannot make it work on the same data!!
I know that the data is loaded:

```
 head(input)
```

Outputs the first 6 lines.

When I use the following code:

```
  thin(  loc.data = input, 
      lat.col = "latitude", long.col = "longitude", 
      pec.col = "species", 
      thin.par = 1, reps = 10, 
      locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, 
      write.files = TRUE, 
      max.files = 10, 
      out.dir = "outputs/", out.base = "Apono", 
      write.log.file = TRUE,
      log.file = "Apono.txt" 
      )
```

The output is

```
    Beginning Spatial Thinning. Script Started at: Tue Mar 07 19:39:06 2023Error 
    in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : attempt to select less than one element in 
    get1index
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: See github issue with the same error: https://github.com/mlammens/spThin/issues/27

Comment: Thanks for that link. All coordinates are in decimal degrees, so that is not the issue.
And that code worked for one data set yesterday and will not work today.
In the second data set, there will be locations < 0.2 km apart.I will deal with that and try again

Comment: I removed all locations closer than 0.2 km and it still would not work, so while I was in QGIS, I removed samples, so all are more than 1 km apart. Tedious, but the job is done!!

Comment: Write up an answer below, for future self, or for other new users having the same issue.